# Select box automatically redirects when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made,options in select box clickable. However for the very first option I din't put any link. But just when I click on the select box it redirects to somewhere and says page not found.

But if you click on the arrow and hold for a while then the dropdown appears.Now when u click any of the option it works. But I wonder why at first it doesn't shows the dropdown and just redirect.

here's the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58cqc812/

HTML

```
<select id="myselect">
   <option>Go To ...</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/">Home</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/page/about-us">About Us &#9662;</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/page/the-centre-point-of-any-web-projects">Centre-Point of Web Projects</option>
   <option><a href="#">Branches &#9662;</a>
        <?php #Core::getHook('block-branches'); ?></option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/news">News</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/event">Events</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/contact">Contact Us</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
<script>
    //$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  //location.href=$(this).data('url');
//});
document.getElementById("myselect").onclick = function(d){
  window.location = this.value;
};
    </script>
```

You can refer to the live site. You need to resize the browser to the smallest, then only this menu appears.It's meant for mobile version.
http://ymm.valse.com.my/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change on click event to change event .... it will fire  when click the select box .

```
     document.getElementById("myselect").onchange = function(d){
       window.location = this.value;
      };
```

i don't exactly know how on change work with JavaScript bcz i prefer jQuery

Comment: This will fire, even if user selects the first option. i.e. "Go To", which I guess the OP does not want.

Comment: yes at on change you have to check if non empty value then only fire ... yes @dev u did is also work well .....

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
$("#myselect").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()!==""){
        window.location = $(this).val();
    }
});
```